# How does SAME padding work in convolution neural networks, when stride is greater than 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, zero-padding

I am trying to implement 2-D convolution in python.
I have an input image set of dimensions (m, 64, 64, 3), where m is the number of images.
I want to use a filter size f=8 and stride=8 for both height and width, and SAME padding so that input width and height (64, 64) are preserved.

Using the formula **[n' = floor((n-f+2*pad)/stride + 1)]** and putting n'=64, n=64, stride=8, f=8, I get **pad=224**, which is unreasonably large.

For example, when I took m, the number of images, as 1080, it presumably resulted in a memory error and my system crashed.

But when I used the Keras library and the following code, it worked fine.

```
X = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(8, 8), padding='same')(X)
```

Here is my implementation of the Conv2D in python:

```
import numpy as np

# A.shape = (1080, 64, 64, 3)
# W.shape = (8, 8, 3, 32)
# b.shape = (32,)

def conv_fwd(A, W, b, pad=0, stride=1):
    pad_A = np.pad(A, ((0, 0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
    (m, w, h, nc) = A.shape
    (fw, fh, ncc, ncn) = W.shape

    if nc != ncc:
        raise Exception('Number of channels in kernel and input do not match')

    wn = int((w-fw+2*pad)/stride + 1)
    hn = int((h-fh+2*pad)/stride + 1)
    A_n = np.zeros((m, wn, hn, ncn))
    W = W.reshape(fw*fh*ncc, ncn)

    for i in range(wn):
        for j in range(hn):
            A_n[:, i, j] = pad_A[:, i*stride:i*stride+fw, j*stride:j*stride+fh].reshape(m, fw*fh*nc).dot(W) + b
    return A_n
```

So I'm assuming there is a different process for calculating the padding in keras. I tried looking for the source code, but couldn't find it. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

In the formula, `n' = floor((n-f+2*pad)/stride + 1` you have taken `n' == n == 64`.

That is not correct. `n' is equal to n` only when value of `Stride is equal to 1` but here, `Stride` is greater than 1 (`8`).

That's the reason you are getting very high value for `Padding`.

Now, as your goal is to find the value of `Padding`, I have a solution/workaround (which might not be very optimized).

Initially, build the Model with `Padding = Same`, as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, strides = (2,2), kernel_size = (3,3), 
input_shape = (64,64,3), padding = 'same'))
print(model.summary())
```

Summary of the Model with `Padding = Same` is shown below:

```
Model: "sequential_12"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 64)        1792      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,792
Trainable params: 1,792
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**If we observe the `Shape` of the `Image`, it is reduced from `(64,64)` to `(32,32)` even though `Padding == Same`.**

Now, build the Model with `Padding = Valid`, as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, strides = (2,2), kernel_size = (3,3), 
input_shape = (64,64,3), padding = 'valid'))
print(model.summary())
```

Summary for the above Model is shown below:

```
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, 31, 31, 64)        1792      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,792
Trainable params: 1,792
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If we observe, the `Shape` of the `Convolutional Layer` is `(None,31,31,64)`.

Now, `Padding` can be obtained by the formula,

```
Height with SAME Padding - Height with VALID Padding
```

or

```
Width with SAME Padding - Width with VALID Padding
```

i.e., **`32 - 31 = 1`**.

**Padding** in your case, with `Input Shape` = `(64, 64,3)`, `Filter Size = 8`, `Strides = 8` is **1** i.e.,

`Input` is **Padded with 1 Row and 1 Column of Zeros**.